# fullcalendar adding & removing events

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to adding & removing events by simply clicking on them,
it works, but if I change month, or I add one more event, it does not longer works..
Something does not work properly:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },
    defaultDate: '2014-11-07',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [{
        id: 'All Day Event',
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2014-11-03'
    }, {
        id: 'popo',
        title: 'popo',
        start: '2014-11-04T10:30:00',
        end: '2014-11-04T12:30:00',
        description: 'This is a cool event',
        color: 'rgb(142, 67, 163)',
        textColor: 'white'
    }, {
        id: 'popo2',
        title: 'popo2',
        //url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2014-11-05'
    }]
});

$('.fc-day').click(function(){
    var myPrompt = prompt('');
    /*$('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
        id: myPrompt,
        title: myPrompt,
        start: $(this).attr('data-date')
    }]);*/

    var newEvent = {
        id: myPrompt,
        title: myPrompt,
        start: $(this).attr('data-date')
    };
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', newEvent , 'stick');

});

$('.fc-content').click(function(){
    var gugu = $(this).children('.fc-title').html();
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', gugu);
});
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**[Demo HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/x17urfo2/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of 
`$('.fc-content').click(function(){` 
use 
`$('#calendar').on('click','.fc-content',function(){`

So it will work for the new dinamicaly created events too.

Comment: Many thanks, I updated all occurences and now everything works fine :)

Comment: I have some troubles with the eventResize and the event.end date.. please have a look to **[this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26814568/fullcalendar-event-end-date-incorrect-after-eventresize)** thanks in advance